# mClass name and mPackage name completely different?

Tags: android

Looking through the runningTask, I found it interesting that some task's class name and package name completely differs (in base Activity).
One of the application I am running is "catchOfTheday".

**Package name is** : `au.com.catchoftheday.android`

**Class name is** : `au.com.mobileandroid.android.main_classes.mainhome.home`

Base activity refers to the initial activity when the application is launched. I checked to see if this class name refers to some other process in runningProcess, but couldnt find. Can anybody please suggest me to understand this behaviour ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> package name is : `au.com.catchoftheday.android`

is application package name specified in the `manifest` file

> class name is :
>   au.com.mobileandroid.android.main_classes.mainhome.home

is the java fully qualified path of that class in app

Comment: Can you make it more clear ? I believe this class must be inside "au.com.mobileandroid......" something package. How can you have a classname that doesnt have any part of the package name ??

Comment: sure. we can. lets say my app package name is "com.xyz.demoapp" but my root java package can easily be different from it e.g. "com.root.mainactivity"